# How to save an audio file from firebase while its streaming

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

So I've been able to setup avplayer to stream the audio directly from firebase link, and I've also been able to set it up to download from firebase. What I'm trying to figure out is if its possible to basically save the file to a file URL while its streaming or when it's done streaming, because performing download task and also setting the players currentitem to stream basically takes twice the network resources.
Also im looking for a swift language solution preferably

Comment: try this https://github.com/vitoziv/VIMediaCache

Comment: thanks, just checked it out but I have tried checking, but still, dont have clarity on this: would I be able to specify a URL for the file to be written to permanently on my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs this I solved it by calling this function when the AVplayeritem finished buffering

```
func saveTrack(asset: AVURLAsset)
{
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)` 

        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("YourApp/documents/Track01.m4a")

        exporter?.outputURL = fileURL
        exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a


        exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            print(exporter?.status)
            print(exporter?.estimatedOutputFileLength)
            print(exporter?.maxDuration)
            print("finished ssaving file")
            print()
        })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "when the AVPlayerItem finished buffering"? How do you know when it finishes?